# I have develop a custom theme in wordpress, but css file could not sound by function.php

Tags: php, css, wordpress

function.php code

```php
function load_css() {
    wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), false,'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');
    wp_register_style('main', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/main.css', array(), false,'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('main');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_css');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code only and remove the 2nd registration style i.e. main.css

```
<?php

    function load_css()
    {
        wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), false, 'all');
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');


    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_css');
```

Comment: Use one style: bootstrap.min.css only
And also load the JS

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok, just replace

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_css');
```

with

```
add_action('init', 'load_css');
```

or

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_style', 'load_css');
```

Comment: thank you so much @Rajan Gupta , I think it will work.